# Editing a python list

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, split

*What I want to do?* 
I want to create a python program that takes a text file, makes the text into a list of strings like this 
 `['Man', 'request', 'adapted', 'spirits', 'set', 'pressed.', 'Up', 'to']` **(1)**
, takes the number of letters of each word into a different list like this 
`[3, 7, 7, 7, 3, 8, 2, 2]`**(2)** 
and checks that if the number of each string element is greater than 3 (*>3*), removes its first letter and adds it to the end of the word with 'xy' string too. The result of the final list should be:
 `['Man', 'equestrxy', 'daptedaxy', 'piritssxy', 'set', 'ressed.pxy', 'Up', 'to']`**(3)** 
*What I have already done?* I have made **(1)** and **(2)** parts of code and I am currently trying the **(3)** .

*My code with comments:*

```
text = open("RandomTextFile.txt").read().split()  #this is the the part (1)
```

```
#function that creates the second part (2)
```

`def map_(A):
  return list(map(len, A))
words = map_(text) #list that contains the example list of (2)`

```
#This is the part (3) and I try to achieve it by creating a loop
for i in range(y):
  if words[i]>3:
      text[i] = [x + string for x in text]
```

Can anyone suggest what I can do to achieve the part (3)? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using list comphrehension

```
>>> x = ['Man', 'request', 'adapted', 'spirits', 'set', 'pressed.', 'Up', 'to']
>>> [i[1:] + i[0] + 'xy' if len(i) > 3 else i for i in x]
```

> ['Man', 'equestrxy', 'daptedaxy', 'piritssxy', 'set', 'ressed.pxy', 'Up', 'to']

Comment: Thanks it works also and it's a much faster in "time" solution!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
def format_strings(strs):
    len_strs = [len(s) for s in strs]
    return [strs[i][1:] + 'xy' if len_str > 3
        else strs[i] for i, len_str in enumerate(len_strs)]
```

Answer (score 1):

For any word like this: `t = 'request'` you can use slicing:

```
t[1:]+t[0]+'xy'
```

Comment: As I checked, slicing is the best method as an asnwer to my question! Thank you.